# Generate Excel Sheet from Html element like div in Asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to export `excel` sheet from `html` formatted `.aspx` page. `Div` element contains `Header`, `Filter`, and `Data` table `Div`. I want to export that as it is.

```
 <div id="dataToshow" class="font-details" runat="server">
        <div id="divHeader" class="clsHeader" runat="server">
            //Contain header info
        </div>
        <div id="divFilter" runat="server">
            //contain filter data
        </div>
        <div id="divReportDetail" class="clsReportDetail" runat="server">            
            //contain data, may be from Asp.net Gridview, Repeater control
        </div>
    </div>
```

i want to export div with id "dataToshow" in exact excel .xlsx format that will be supported by google excel spreadsheet. Please help, All i am doing on Asp.net c#

Edited:

Actually I want to send generated `excel` sheet to `Email` using `.net SmtpClient Class`. I have my code:

```
StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
HtmlTextWriter hw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);
this.dataToshow.RenderControl(hw);
ExportAndEmail eae = new ExportAndEmail();
eae.ExportAndEmailDocument(sw, type,"Report", EmailID, EmailSubject);
```

`ExportAndEmailDocument` Function:

```
if (type == "Excel")
{
    filename = filename + ".xls";
    MemoryStream mstream = new MemoryStream();
    mstream.Write(excel, 0, excel.Length);
    mstream.Position = 0;
    mail.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(mstream, filename, "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet"));
}...
```

`Email` is being sent , but `gmail` spread sheet opening my `.xlsx` sheet as `pdf` document. I need help to open that file also in google spread sheet.

Comment: What code do you have so far? and what have you tried?

Comment: I have code: StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
            HtmlTextWriter hw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);
            this.dataToshow.RenderControl(hw);
            ExportAndEmail eae = new ExportAndEmail();
            eae.ExportAndEmailDocument(sw, type,"BillReport", EmailID, EmailSubject);

Comment: What kind of help do you need? All I can see is *"write it for me"* type question